# Authentication for both ASP.NET Core 2 MVC and WebAPI in the same webapp

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Today, I have a ASP.NET Core 2 web app which contains standard cookie-based authentication for use with the MVC frontend with razor views, and also a WebAPI with JWT for use via other front-ends.

With this, the same user can log in via a MVC razor webpage and via a WebAPI call and access the protected actions for each. These two parts are working fine, but independent of one another.

What I would like to do now is to extend parts of my MVC front-end to use VueJS and call my WebAPI behind the scenes.

When a user logs in via the MVC webapp, the ASP.NET Core 2 middleware creates the cookie and provides in back to the user. But when I want to make requests via VueJS into my WebAPI I need to also have a JWT to pass in the header.

The part I'm struggling with is how to get a JWT when the user logs in via the MVC webpage in addition to the cookie. In the MVC login action, I of course can generate the JWT, but how do I get this back to the user and store it in localStorage?

Here is my current Login action in my MVC controller (very similar to template):

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");

                var userToVerify = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);

                var identity = await Task.FromResult(_jwtFactory.GenerateClaimsIdentity(model.Email, userToVerify.Id));

                // At this point 'jwt' contains the complete token object I would need to store in localStorage
                var jwt = await Tokens.GenerateJwt(identity, _jwtFactory, model.Email, _jwtOptions, new JsonSerializerSettings { Formatting = Formatting.Indented });

                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: And where's your code?

Comment: Added current Login MVC action

Comment: You could append the JWT to the return URL and then have that page run some script to put it into local storage.

Comment: I appreciate the response. I ended up going a different direction and including the login portion of the web app in VueJS. From there I retrieve the token and store it in local storage. I'm slowly converting other authenticated MVC paths over to using only Web API.